# REST API certificates in IntelliJ Selenium project

Tags: api, rest, selenium-webdriver, curl, intellij-idea

I got stuck lately trying to understand how to setup environment in IntelliJ for some specific API which requires `.key` `.crt` `.p12` and `password/passphrase`. While I got everything setup correctly in Postman I cant really set it up in my Selenium framework.
I was told to use `cURL` commands to work it out but that's not fully working for me...I'm using this command

```
curl.exe -v --key X.Y.key --cert X.Y.crt -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d {} https://endpoint.xxx
```

After running this command I'm prompted to `"Enter host password for user 'tFormat':"`

Is this my username (different from X.Y.key name?)
From my company I received `.key`/.`crt`/`p12` file including passphrase all working in Postman but when I tried to type my password I cant see anything typing but anyway I'm getting:

```
* Connected to endpoint.xxx (11.22.33.44) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: Failed to import cert file X.Y.crt, last error is 0x80092002
```

I also tried `--user "name:password"` (which should be `"tFormat:passphrase"` or `"X.Y:passphrase"`) with different configurations of name and password but with no positive results.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong or anyway how can I use command line code inside my methods?

Thanks

Comment: for cURL error see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215236/c-libcurl-schannel-failed-to-import-cert-file-cert-cer-last-error-is-0x8009

Comment: for Selenium, seems like you'd just need to add it to your cert store, but there are some settings you can configure regarding SSL/certs... what errors do you see when running Selenium?

Comment: Error is: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Default APIInvoke method in my framework does not include certificate data. I need to find a way to pass it into that method. I've got my certificate added into File/Setting/Tools/Server

Comment: did you add to the browser?: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3505249?hl=en

Comment: So if this works manually but not automated, you may just need to choose a profile for Selenium to use.  (one with the cert installed)  You may also want to review this FAQ topic: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/data/ssl/chrome_root_store/faq.md