# Using requests to generate an Access Token

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, oauth

As the title says, I'm trying to use requests to get an OAuth2.0 Access Token for an API. They recommend using cUrl, but I'm not really knowledgeable enough to troubleshoot that.

They recommend using this:

`curl -k -d "grant_type=client_cert" --basic -u "{value1}:{value2}" -H "ContentType: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --cert path/to/pem url`

I kept getting an error that said:

> curl: (58) schannel: Failed to import cert file path/to/pem, last error is 0x80092002

and every solution I found on so wasn't helping

They alternatively recommended keys to pass the -u values as form parameters, so what I wrote was this:

```
import requests
res=requests.get('url',params={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},data={'grant-type':'client-cert'},headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},verify='path/to/pem')
```

I've tried changing a few things, but no matter what, I keep getting the same SSL error:

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='url', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: {params} (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)')))

Any suggestions for the request or cUrl knowledge would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71496170/11474852) is an answer to a very similar question that seemed to help. It seems that curl changed the handling of ssl certificates in a recent update. Don't know though what the proper way to use ssl with curl is, now.