# convert curl certificate command to Delphi Indy http.post

Tags: delphi, curl, post, certificate

I'm trying to convert this request:

```http
POST /oauth/token HTTPS/1.1 
Host: psd2.mtls.sandbox.apis.op.fi
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&scope=accounts&client_id=<APP_CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<APP_CLIENT_SECRET>
```

and corresponding cURL command:

```
curl -vk --key key.pem --cert client.crt https://psd2.mtls.sandbox.apis.op.fi/oauth/token -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=accounts&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>'
```

to work with Indy in Delphi 11.

I have searched many days and webpages, and tried tens of examples without success.

I have these `key.pem` and `client.crt` files in the same folder as my code/exe, but I always get this reply:

```http
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

My code:

```pascal
var
  url,data : string;
  tiedot : TStringList;
  PostData: TStringStream;
  Result,sWhichFail, sVer: String;
begin
  tiedot := TStringList.Create();
  try
    url := 'https://psd2.mtls.sandbox.apis.op.fi/oauth/token';

    {not working way either:
    tiedot.Add('grant_type=client_credentials');
    tiedot.Add('scope=accounts');
    tiedot.Add('client_id=6G..03');
    tiedot.Add('client_secret=7P..W7');
    }
    data := 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=accounts'+
      '&client_id=6G..03&client_secret=7P..W7';
    try
      PostData := TStringStream.Create(data, TEncoding.UTF8);
      ClientSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      ClientSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
      ClientSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      ClientSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
      ClientSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'client.cer';
      ClientSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'key.pem';
      http.HandleRedirects  := True;
      http.IOHandler := ClientSSLIOHandler;
      http.AllowCookies := True;

      //none of these are working better
      http.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
      //http.HTTPOptions := [];
      //http.HTTPOptions := http.HTTPOptions + [hoNoProtocolErrorException, hoWantProtocolErrorContent];

      http.Request.BasicAuthentication := false;
      http.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      http.Request.CharSet := 'UTF-8';

      try
        result := http.post(url,PostData); //tiedot -not working either
        mLoki.Lines.Add(result);
      except
        on E: EIdOSSLCouldNotLoadSSLLibrary do begin
          sVer := OpenSSLVersion();
          sWhichFail := WhichFailedToLoad();//uses IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders
          mLoki.Lines.Add(sVer);
          mLoki.Lines.Add(sWhichFail);
          ShowMessage('Could not load OpenSSL');
        end;
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
          mLoki.Lines.Add('HTTP Failure');
          mLoki.Lines.Add(Format('- Response Code: %d', [http.ResponseCode]));
          mLoki.Lines.Add(Format('- Response Text: %s', [http.ResponseText]));
          mLoki.Lines.Add('- '+E.ErrorMessage);
          ShowMessage('HTTP Failure');
        end;
        on E: Exception do begin
          mLoki.Lines.Add(E.ClassName);
          mLoki.Lines.Add(E.Message);
          ShowMessage('Unknown Error');
        end;
      end;
    finally
      PostData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    tiedot.Free;
  end;
```

I think that the certificate part is working correctly, because my log response is as follows:

```
tilatieto: Resolving hostname psd2.mtls.sandbox.apis.op.fi.
tilatieto: Connecting to 18.159.93.42.
tilainfo: SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
tilainfo: SSL status: "before/connect initialization"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv2/v3 write client hello A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 read server hello A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 read server key exchange A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 read server certificate request A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 read server done A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 write client certificate A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 write client key exchange A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 write certificate verify A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 write change cipher spec A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 write finished A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 flush data"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSLv3 read finished A"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
tilainfo: Cipher: name = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256; description = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
; bits = 128; version = TLSv1/SSLv3; 
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
tilainfo: SSL status: "SSL negotiation finished successfully"
tilatieto: Disconnected.
HTTP Failure
- Response Code: 400
- Response Text: HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
- {"message":"Bad Request"}
```

The problem is that I get that "Bad Request". I am thinking that the posting format is still incorrect, but I don't know what to change or test next.

---

SIDE NOTE:
I also mention that I could not get that curl command working on my Windows 11 command prompt, it gives error:

- schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
- schannel: Failed to import cert file client.crt, last error is 0x80092002

But that is not my big problem and question. I want to do this with Delphi.

Sure, it would have been helpful if it worked with curl, and then I could have checked Wireshark for differences, but that is another story.

Comment: Using a `TStringList` is the correct and preferred way to send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with `TIdHTTP`. But your `TStringStream` approach will work, too. Why can't you compare curl's request to `TIdHTTP`'s request for differences?  You can configure both to output the raw HTTP messages in plain text outside of the TLS encryption.

Comment: Regarding the schannel certificate error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64215236/

Comment: Thanks Remy. These SSL things are very new to me and also curl commands and settings. I have programming 30 years but never needed these kind of things. So I'll try to update my knowledge now.. I found how to show raw http request from curl but problem is that this example curl command doesn't work on my computer, it gives those "schannel errors". So I have nothing to compare for Delphi Indy http.post conversion.. So is the best/only way solve this problem, first get this curl working and then compare its raw request to Delphi or can I still try something modification to current Delphi code?

Comment: A wild shot, but it can sometimes be problematic to specify multiple allowed SSLVersions, such as [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2]. Not all servers understand that well. It might help to specify just one single allowed value, probably then [sslvTLSv1_2], since it's the only one of those that is regarded safe nowaydays.

Comment: @Juha "*is the best/only way solve this problem, first get this curl working and then compare its raw request to Delphi*" - I would suggest that, yes. Curl or Postman. You need a working baseline first on which to then base your Delphi code.

Comment: I have stuck on this CURL's 58 error.  I have also tried connection to badssl.com with "youtube instruction" but that gives same error, even any tested certificate. * Connected to client.badssl.com (104.154.89.105) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: Failed to import cert file OP_client_cert.pem, last error is 0x80092002